# WP Multisite 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I installed WP Multisite on a wp site and got an internal server error, which is caused by the new .htaccess. 
I copied the code from the wordpress multisite installation in the backend.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) mysite/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ mysite/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Can anybody give me a hint why the error occurs?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite loaded on your server? Anything in the error log?

Comment: I just have a partial ftp access, so I can't access the error logs :/

Comment: Before I installed the  multisite everything worked fie ( with the basic wp htaccess )

Comment: mod_rewrite is installed

Comment: At least on my test env, the .htaccess doesn't lead to a 500 response. Are you sure it's because of the .htaccess (does requesting static files such as images lead to a 500, too? do those requests work if you rename the .htaccess to something else?)?

Comment: Static paths doesn't work too. I'm quite sure because when I use the old htaccess (backup version) I get access to the frontend, but not to the backend. If I use old htaccess + old wpconfig I get access to backend + frontend.

Comment: when I rename the htaccess I get access to the page... (?)

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe comment out lines from the .htaccess until you find what is causing the problem? It's not a syntax error, so I'm guessing you're hitting a rewrite limit, but that's pure speculation.

Comment: It was because of the BOM encryption of my editor (I use atom). I got to delete the BOM manually via 

 find . -type f -iname "*.php" -exec sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' -i.bak {} \; -exec rm {}.bak \;

and

find . -type f -iname ".htaccess" -exec sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' -i.bak {} \; -exec rm {}.bak \;